# Why is Visual Studio Debugger automatically closing when running the swagger?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, api, visual-studio-debugging

I am facing an stranger issue when I try to debug one of my api via Swagger. If I remove the debugger points, the swagger automatically closes without showing the output. However, if I add debugger points, the debugger stops working and a pop-up is displayed showing the message `the target process exited with code 1073741819 while evaluating a function`.

Here is the pop-up that I have mentioned:
[image]

Here is the api that I am getting this issue on:

```
[HttpGet("feerate")]
public async Task<ActionResult<ResponseVM>> GetFeeRate(FeeName feeName, FeeSchedule feeSchedule, FeeUnit feeUnit, int vcu)
{
    try
    {
        var rv = await service.GetFeeRate(feeName, feeSchedule, feeUnit, vcu);
        return Ok(new ResponseVM
        {
            success = true,
            data = rv,
            message = "Fee rate fetched successfully"
        });
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Ok(new ResponseVM
        {
            success = false,
            message = ex.Message
        });
    }
}
```

Here is the service function:

```
public async Task<PaginatedResponseVM<FeeScheduleDto>> GetFeeRate(FeeName feeName, FeeSchedule feeSchedule, FeeUnit feeUnit, int vcu)
{

    var accQueryList = _dbContext.FeeSchedule.Where(x => x.FeeSchedule == feeSchedule);
    accQueryList = accQueryList.Where(x => x.FeeName == feeName);
    accQueryList = accQueryList.Where(x => x.FeeUnit == feeUnit);
    accQueryList = accQueryList.Where(x => x.TierStart <= vcu);
    accQueryList = accQueryList.Where(x => x.TierEnd > vcu);

    var count = await accQueryList.CountAsync();

    var items = _mapper.Map<List<FeeScheduleDto>>(await accQueryList.ToListAsync());

    var returnView = new PaginatedResponseVM<FeeScheduleDto>(count, items);

    return returnView;

}
```

Here is what I tried to resolve it:

1. Restarted my PC
2. Upgraded Visual Studio version
3. Repaired the Visual Studio via Control Panel
4. Cleaned the solution and Rebuild it

But the issue persists, so is there anyone who faced a similar issue and how it was resolved?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to get the error code correct, it is actually -1073741819.  Googles really, really well.  Failed debugger expressions is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @HansPassant I tried googling it, and most of the replies have mentioned about repairing the VS or restarting the PC, but that is not helping.

Comment: Yes, repairing and updating VS are very good ideas.  If that doesn't help then use Help > Send Feedback  > Report a Problem.

Comment: @HansPassant I don't think that is the solution.

Comment: The intention of Help > Send Feedback is to get in touch with the people that have the solution for a problem like this.  We can now actually see the message box, it gives you a specific workaround.  Did you try it?  You never mentioned the VS version you used, it matters.  If you're on VS2022, especially version 17.4 and up then you want to try VS2019, it is much more stable.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/379441/error-code-exited-with-code-1073741819 read both, the comments and answer from user "RLWA32".

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your insights and I will definitely give it a try. The version is 17.4, the latest one.

Comment: Do you have to use this evaluation feature? If no, try to follow Tools -> Options -> Debugging -> General -> and then [unselect Enable property evaluation and other implicit function calls](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JLEU.png). After that, see whether the issue still pop out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everyone thank you for all your replies and insights. However, the problem was with my Enum that I had used in the Dto file in the wrong manner. As the pop-up error says, I had to check again and again and at last correct my silly mistake.
So, while the enum is converted to string, the enum variable should be converted to string rather than the returning string variable itself.
Here is the correct way:

```
public FeeScheduleEnum FeeSchedule { get; set; }
public string FeeScheduleName { get { return FeeSchedule.ToString(); } }
```

So, this is where I had done that silly mistake:

```
public FeeScheduleEnum FeeSchedule { get; set; }
public string FeeScheduleName { get { return FeeScheduleName.ToString(); } }
```

Posting my answer here for anyone else doing that same mistake as I did.